# 'Now' Function query in php to get current date and time

Tags: php, function, datetime

what's the query to get current data and time from 'now' function in php.
my code is here:

```
$time=SELECT NOW();
echo $time;
```

But not working please guide me how can I do this?

Comment: this is not even a valid php code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Need to execute query if you want to get current date and time in PHP. Check below date function

```
<?php echo date('d-M-Y H:i:s'); ?>
```

Comment: he want this mysq why you used php function

Comment: At least it's better than querying MySQL only for the time, that seems silly. Asking PHP is a lot faster and simpler.

Comment: Yes Agree... No need to execute query to get date & time only.

Answer (score 0):

This will fetch current time from Database.

```
<?php 

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT NOW()";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    echo $result->fetch_assoc()['NOW()'];
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

But we can do it using PHP [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

```
echo date('m/d/Y h:i:s a');
```